Eclipse Scout CSP in Java/Javascript
I need help for the dynamic loading of javascripts in Eclipse Scout.
So I already have a javascript that is called from an index.ts to put the scripts and the meta tag for CSP in the head section. There are many examples of how this can be done.
My problem is rather that ‘unsafe’ is usually used for local projects etc., which in my case is not the case. And even if I use the examples without ‘unsafe’, e.g.
const meta = document.createElement('meta');
meta.httpEquiv = "Content-Security-Policy";
meta.content = "script-src 'self' /myDirectory/myFile.js;"
document.head.appendChild(meta);

it simply does not work on my domain. The relative path is definitely correct, because if I write ./ as a relative path, for example, I am told that the script was not found or is an invalid source.
And the meta tag, as well as the script tags, are also inserted in the head area, except that the scripts are not loaded because of the CSP error.
My error message looks like this: "Refused to load the script '' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback."
I had also thought about allowing the scripts for Eclipse Scout, unfortunately I have not yet found a way to do this, if it is possible at all.
In principle, I would also assume that the time interval between inserting the script tag, meta tag for CSP and loading the scripts does not fit, but since I am not particularly experienced in this area, I cannot say any more about this.

And now, for some reason, I have the error message ‘The source list for Content Security Policy directive “script-src” contains an invalid source: “/myDirectory/myFile.js”. It is ignored’ for my relative paths. Can anyone explain why this error occurs?

I solved the problem.
I just have to add the paths I need, in the ‘getFilterExludes’ method in UiServletContributors (version 24 and higher).

script-src 'self' means, that only scripts from the same domain as the html page are allowed to be loaded. Since this is the default for a Scout app, I don't think you need to adjust the CSP rules.
How do you load the script exactly? You can use $.injectScript(url) to dynamically load scripts.
I would check the following:

Remove the "/" at the beginning of your script path to make it a relative path.
Verify the path is correct and the script is available by pasting the URL
into the browsers address bar. You can use the dev tools of the browser
(F12) to get the URL of the request.
In case your script is not hosted on the same domain, adjust the CSP rule of the html page by setting the config property scout.cspDirective. Example: scout.cspDirective[script-src]='self' https://script-domain.com


For some reason I can't use the injectScript Method, I get an Error

but actually I think the problem is with the login.
Currently I have solved the loading in the base URL with full paths, but the loading in the login page doesn't work. It's probably because the login page is a subdomain, which is why I can't load the scripts, but I'm not sure about that. Currently I use the code:
const script = document.createElement(‘script’);
script.src = ‘https://baseUrl/myDirectory/myFile.js’;
document.head.appendChild(script);

And the code shown above for CSP with full path only.
Locally, a distinction is made between login and application, but in the ‘public’ domain I get directly on the login page, although the base URL is specified in the URL and the base URL is generally addressed first. That's why it shouldn't matter whether I load the scripts in the login and the base URL or only in the base URL, but even if I want to load the scripts in the index.ts and the login.ts, it doesn't work.
Here is the current error I get:
"Refused to load the script '' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback."
"Refused to load the script 'http://baseUrl/login' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback."
